# Idea restore data instance by snapshot openstack!

Tags: openstack, snapshot

My wish is to restore the instance's data back to the data of any created snapshot and keep the IP assigned to that instance.

**I have tried a few ideas with no success:**

1. From the snapshot create a new volume then assign that volume to the instance. Then detach the root volume of the instance then attach the new volume to the instance but not always get the error "Can't detach root device".
2. From the snapshot I create the volume then create a new instance complete with the same flavor + image configuration as the instance I want to restore. Then it will separate the IP in the original instance to assign it to the new instance. This option is possible, but the probability of losing the ip is yes because when separating the ip from the original instance, that IP will be public and can be assigned to another instance when initializing at the same time *(the system automatically gets the public ips). to assign to the instance)* or the process of assigning that ip to the instance of the snapshot is delayed, error. So following this option is very risky not to do.
   Help me with ideas for optimal development. I work through the openstack API using endpoints.

Comment: What kind of IP are you referring to, an internal IP from a self-service network or a floating IP or an IP from a provider network? Since you mention "public IP" I assume it's a floating IP. Usually you can disassociate a floating IP without releasing it, so if you delete a VM which had a floating IP attached the IP is just detached and you should be able to attach it to a new VM. Or does your provider work differently?

Comment: thanks for answer! I tried one method

Comment: And did it work? If yes, what was the method?

Comment: i want restore instance by snapshot. i can't change volume status to "available", so i think create new instance by snapshot and change instance IP. And now i can change volume status by admin role. i don't need create new instance and change ip bro. Thanks you very much. Can you help me in topic : https://serverfault.com/questions/1129214/instance-and-restore-volume-by-backup-openstack