# Instance and restore volume by backup openstack

Tags: openstack

I try to restore volume with backup_id using rest api and it was successful. But while the restore is in progress, I call the api to create another instance. I don't understand why the instance is not created. Is it possible during the restore process to create an instance. If so, is there any real solution?

Comment: You mean you want to launch that exact instance which you're currently recovering? I don't think it's possible. Which errors do you get while the instance is failing?

Comment: no bro. i call first rest api to restore volume by backup, backup size over 200G, The process completes about 20 minutes. And when first call runs for 5 minutes. i call sencond rest api to create new instance by different volume. But second call don't preccess. It waits first call to finish executing before doing it

Comment: Please provide more details what exactly you're doing, explicitly which api calls you're executing (although I won't be able to help with those). But maybe there's an option to not wait for the previous call to finish? I know of the opposite with openstack cli:
`root@control01:~# openstack help server create | grep wait
                               [--wait]
  --wait                Wait for build to complete`